# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I have come accross the following sum
\begin{align}
s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
\end{align}
Can we obtain some closed-form expression with respect to $p$ for this summation? I found that it may be related to the Legendre polynomials $P_n(x)$,
\begin{align}
P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 (x-1)^{n-k} (x+1)^k.
\end{align}
However, it is not trivial to apply these Legendre polynomials. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks in adavance.

Comment: In what context did you find/construct this sum $s_n$?

Comment: You can verify using the quoted formula for the Legendre polynomials that $$
s_n  = (2p - 1)^n \cdot P_n \!\left( {\frac{1}{{2p - 1}}} \right).
$$ For $p=1/2$, one has to understand it as a limiting case $p\to 1/2$.

Comment: @Gary, this expression does not have a singularity at $p=1/2$, $(2p-1)^n$ kills all denominators.

Comment: @markvs Yes, it is a removable singularity.

Comment: @Gary: Right! ${}$

Comment: Oh! thank you all for the comments, and it helps a lot.